# Gradient solver

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

my question is about gradient algorithms.

Lets have function f like:
$f(x) = \|Ax-b\|^2$
and i want to find its minimum (according to x). So i can use some gradient method, for instance gradient descent (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent).

I would like to know, if there is algorithm solving above expression with parameter A:
min $f(A) = \|Ax-b\|^2$ (or some other functions like $\|x_i-x_j\|_A = \sqrt{(x_i-x_j)^TA(x_i-x_j)}$). And what would it look like.

I could only find solutions with argument x. Thanks.

**EDIT:**
For clarification i make an example.
From wiki, there exist solution for this problem: $f(x) = \|Ax-b\|^2$
We can use (for instance) conjugate gradient algorithm as follows (from wiki):

1. $\mathbf{r}_0 := \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{A x}_0 \,$
2. $\mathbf{p}_0 := \mathbf{r}_0 \,$
3. $k := 0 \, $
4. **repeat**
5. - $\alpha_k := \frac{\mathbf{r}_k^\mathrm{T}
         \mathbf{r}_k}{\mathbf{p}_k^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{A p}_k}  \, $
6. - $\mathbf{x}_{k+1} := \mathbf{x}_k + \alpha_k \mathbf{p}_k \, $
7. - $\mathbf{r}_{k+1} := \mathbf{r}_k - \alpha_k \mathbf{A p}_k \, $
8. - if rk+1 is sufficiently small then exit loop end if
9. - $\beta_k := \frac{\mathbf{r}_{k+1}^\mathrm{T}
         \mathbf{r}_{k+1}}{\mathbf{r}_k^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{r}_k}  \, $
10. - $\mathbf{p}_{k+1} := \mathbf{r}_{k+1} + \beta_k \mathbf{p}_k \,$ $k
           := k + 1 \, $
11. **end repeat**

Then my question is, what if the unknown parameter is A, not x (A is number matrix, x,b  are column vectors). How would be defined the problem and how would change the algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are asking how to write the linear map $A \mapsto A x$ in the usual manner of a matrix multiplied by a parameter vector.

Represent $A$ by a vector $\hat A \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, where $\hat A =(A_{1,1},...,A_{1,n},A_{2,1},...,A_{n,1},...,A_{n,n})^T$, and let $\hat x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times {n^2}}$ be 
$$\hat x = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
x^T & 0 & ... & 0\\
0 & x^T & ... & 0 \\
\vdots& & & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & ... & x^T
\end{array} \right)$$

then you can apply your gradient method to solve $\min_A ||\hat x\hat A - b ||^2$.

Comment: Thank you for answer. As i understand, you just swap the A and x parameters? Is not the same? If so, this is not exactly what i was looking for, but thanks anyway :]. Maybe i wrote it little bit confused. Suppose for example function $\|x_i-x_j\|_A = \sqrt{(x_i-x_j)^TA(x_i-x_j)}$. Here, x are vectors (x = column vector [1 2 3 ... n]) and A is number matrix. And i want to minimize that function according to A.

Comment: I updated main post (above) for clarification.

Comment: In the conjugate gradient algorithm above, replace $x$ by $\hat A$, $x_0$ by your initial value $\hat A_0$, replace $A$ by $\hat x$. As far as I can tell, that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, i couldn't see it yesterday, but i get it now! This can be applicable, thank you very much :]

Answer (score 0):

It's called [Weighted least squares](http://www.google.co.il/url?url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares%23Weighted_least_squares&rct=j&q=Weighted+least+squares&usg=AFQjCNH5Af_q31U-51xW5GcpDAl8MeXQrw&sa=X&ei=5DKUT8nJBo2ZOtWImPQD&ved=0CC8QygQwAA).

Comment: Thank you for answer. I looked at it but im not sure if this solves my question. I made some clarification in the comment above.